# What stops the United States from becoming "undemocratic"?

Tags: united-states, constitution, democracy

Hypothetically, let's say the conservatives in America were to run on a religious platform and win with an overwhelming majority. What stops them from voting out the current constitution and re-writing it to a theocracy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a prediction about a hypothetical situation that is unrealistic and off topic

Comment: @SoylentGray why is this off-topic? Im asking how democracies safeguard their democracy. Look at my initial question before it was edited

Comment: Because it is asking about a possible future event.  It can only be answered with speculation, and because the event is not even remotely imminent much more speculation than normal us required.

Comment: @SoylentGray the EXAMPLE that was given is not even remotely possible, but the basic question is very possible and asking a simple question.

Comment: Hypoteticals are supposed to be off topic... https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/are-questions-calling-for-speculation-on-current-or-future-events-on-topic - This question is no different to me than if you asked "If the sky turned to blood and we all adapted to breathe it how would that affect our government."

Comment: @SoylentGray the original question was not hypothetical. The question was how do democracies protect their democracy due to the fact that it simply can be voted out.

Comment: That is too broad.  You could has how does a specific party try to do that.  But there are limitless ways they could do it.

Answer (score 18):

The system of government in the United States, however, is explicitly designed to make such an overwhelming majority very difficult to achieve.

According to the law, there are 2 ways that a constitutional amendment can be proposed:

1. Constitutional convention approved by two thirds of the states legislatures
2. Proposal by both two thirds of the house and two thirds of the senate

In order for an amendment to be **ratified**, you need approval of three quarters of states.

See [Constitutional Amendment Process](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/constitution)

---

So if you have enough support, you can legally change the constitution to whatever you want.  The difficulty is actually getting that much support.  The amount of support you'll need in order to overturn democracy would have be truly overwhelming, and that is not feasible to achieve in a culture that all but worships the concept of Democracy.

---

Of course there's always the extra-legal option.  If the country is unanimous about something, there's little that can stop them.  In fact, they can just up and ignore the constitution and draft a new one.  The constitution isn't magic; it's power is derived from people's willingness to abide by it.

This doesn't necessarily have to be a majority of the people either.  If you can get control of enough of the military, then a coup can happen.

Comment: It would be less about control of the military, and more about the support of the military. Pedantic, but important.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - If you are going to stage a coup you are going to need both...

Answer (score 7):

The primary road block in the path of any monolithic group of angry [group] enacting [oppressive] goals: these United States are a Republic, not a Democracy. Inasmuch a democracy is the tyranny of the majority, a republic restrains the will of the majority through a set of restrictive laws intended to limit government power.

Despite all indications to the contrary, to include the corruptibility of man, obnoxious weight of special interests, and more, these United States were built as a Republic, with a limited government that gains power from the populace.

> Disclaimer: Yes, there were compromises and villainous actions at the founding of the country as well, but that doesn't negate the desired result.

Any effort to greatly undo the protection of individual rights codified by the Constitution would require actions in accordance with Article V of the same, violent over throw of the government, or the willful surrender and abdication of individual freedoms by the populace.

Putting aside a violent overthrow of the government, since the impacts of such an event would go well beyond installing a simple theocracy, focus on the other two. They are inextricably linked, given the full weight of the requirements to amend the Constitution in accordance with Article V. 3/4 of the States would have to ratify any amendment. That means 3/4ths of the state legislatures would also need to be in [group] control. How large do you think [group] is, as a proportion of the populace?

The last condition, where the populace surrenders and abdicates their individuals freedoms, is the most threatening because we can see indications that it is already happening. Look at the expanse of the Federal government beyond the confines of the Constitution, how it inserts itself into matters beyond its powers, and people accept it because "[general welfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_welfare_clause)," an illusion of [security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_theater), or personal gain.

Comment: while I believe your correct about the populace surrendering their individual freedoms. I disagree with the acceptance as "general welfare" but as "increased security", much like how intelligence agencies no longer need warrants to investigate citizens.

Comment: Why do you think that being a republic has some sort of magical power to override the will of the "overwhelming majority" of the people that the question talks about? That overwhelming majority has taken control of two of the branches of government; what do you think the judiciary is going to do about it? Nothing, because the judiciary can't impose anything on an overwhelming majority who are intent on changing the system.

Comment: @Reed Meant as a reference to the expansive nature of the general welfare clause under current interpretations. The measures to bypass the Fourth Amendment are still unConstitutional.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Because the Powers of the Federal Government is Restricted. Under what measures are they going to enforce sweeping changes to the Constitution without the support of state governments?

Comment: @DrunkCynic That's a property of the federal system, not of being a republic. But you've overlooked the fact that the state and federal governments are voted for by the same people. They're not going to vote for a crazy theocracy at the federal level but vote Democrats and Republicans into their state legislatures.

Answer (score 3):

This could just as easily apply to a left wing group, wanting to legalize discrimination against anyone who doesn't agree with them.

One political group would have to take over congress, the presidency, and most state governments.

They could amend the constitution, which requires the president, congress, and the majority of states to agree on, and also requires a lot of time - constitutional amendments can drag on for decades, as each state sets its own timetable on ratification. So the political group that seized control, would have to maintain that control for at least a couple of decades, probably longer.

In the interim, such a group would probably fracture from internal disagreements, fall into disfavor, and the amendments would either not make it out of congress, or would not be ratified by the requisite number of states.

This is one time that the wheels of government turning as slowly as they do, works to the advantage of all of us. It slows radical change to give the electorate plenty of time to consider the ramifications, and consequences, of that change.

Comment: While the president of course wields a lot of political power, his agreement is not required for a constitutional amendment. Regarding timescales, a number of recent amendment proposals have set a 7-year limit for ratification by the states to stop matters dragging on (like, most notably, the 27th amendment, [which took 202 years to ratify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-seventh_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution)!).

Answer (score 2):

In the United States specifically, it would ultimately be up to the voters to stop them but, seeing as how the voters were the ones that put those representatives there in the first place, there wouldn't be much to do to stop them should they have *enough support*.

But that's how democracy works. If you support the notion that governments derive their power from the people that they represent, when the people indicate they want something (like electing super-majorities of people who run for office on theocratic platforms), then government is supposed to oblige.

In the U.S., thankfully, that would take *a lot of support*. The opportunistic theocrats would have to, at the very least, modify the first amendment [which would be hard](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/constitution). If the theocrats decide *not* to modify the election process itself, then voters would have chances in future elections to vote people in to undo whatever they decided to do, so democracy itself would survive. The unelected federal judiciary could serve as a potential stop-gap in the form of striking down new laws that conflict with the constitution, but since I believe we're assuming the constitution will change in all of this through the legislature that may not be viable for too long.

If they *did* decide to do away with elections by amending the Constitution, then there wouldn't be much that anyone would be able to do short of popular revolt. But, assuming that the politicians who made it in to office were voted in with *an overwhelming amount* of public support, I wouldn't expect to see that happen.

I would like to stress that doing away with those protections in the U.S. would require so much support that, even if it's not *impossible* it is exceedingly unlikely in a climate where we sometimes have difficulty even agreeing on [definitions of common words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_of_Bill_Clinton). The terror and beauty of democratic freedom is that if we want to give it away or simply choose not to decide, we can, but you can't do that if you don't have any freedom to begin with.

Comment: Also, remember that the US has two year terms for the House of Representatives. If enough people disagree with a direction, they can elect enough congresspeople to put a stop to the direction. That is counterbalanced by 4 year presidential and 6 year senate terms, so a reactionary House midterm can't control, but it can stop. This was amply demonstrated in 2010, and may be re-demonstrated in 2018.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly the people of the United States.  Even most of the highly devout christian conservatives understands why putting the church in charge of the government is a bad idea.  But even if you could get every christian in the United States to agree that a Theocracy is a good thing, the decision on which religion gets to dominate would divide them as bitterly, and perhaps even more bitterly, than any policy issue to date including going back to the civil war.  And diving further down the hypothetical rabbit hole, even if all those groups could come behind a single denomination, which specific branch of that domination would become another huge battle.  And the reality is you are never going to get the Catholics, Baptists, Methodists, Lutherans, and Mormons to ever agree to allow any other denomination besides their own to dominate.  The tenets of each religion make their beliefs in how things should be in a theocracy would not permit it.

But most people in the US, even those with strong religious convictions, would never want their church running the government.  Taking away the choice to follow the tenets of your religion stops being about having faith in a higher power and wanting a place in heaven and become just a matter of following the law.  That is not a holy and blessed devotion and demonstration of self discipline, and becomes an oppressive and eventually corrupted institution for self gain rather than the glory of god.

Comment: The question presupposes that an "overwhelming majority" of the people want the theocracy. So the people are not a defence in this situation: the people _are_ this situation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Yes but the reality is that even though the majority may want a theocracy there is no way they will agree to any version of the theocracy except their preferred version... unless one of those factions were to get close to a majority (40%+) there is no way.  I doubt when you break it down by specific denomination you are going to see any more than about 7% which is roman Catholicism right now.  or 11% which is just baptists but even there Southern Baptist is around 3% which is the largest faction of baptists...

Comment: I don't think that's a reasonable reading of the question. The question, to me, is about the overwhelming majority of the people voting for the same party, not about them all saying "We want theocracy!" but disagreeing on what kind.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - But that question ignores reality... that is the point of my answer.  In theory yes it is possible but its an unrealistic possibility.  Its possible the world is going to collapse into a singularity at any moment or even just cease to exist.  And the reality is, that is probably more likely than getting the different denominations to agree on how a theocracy should be implemented.  And before you can change to a new form of government you would have to overcome that hurdle

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely nothing.  It can certainly happen, if the popular mood turns especially extreme, or even apathetic, though that's not the same as saying it would be likely or easy.

In fact, there is a current movement being pushed by conservatives where they want to hold a Constitutional Convention.  The claim is that they want to pass a balanced budget amendment.  Opponents claim this is just the more popular window dressing to open the door to a Convention, and that they have a broader agenda.

[Stackexchange question where Constitutional Conventions are discussed.](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15101/why-do-some-people-say-cenk-uygurs-wolfpac-wont-work)

One of the main objections to altering the Constitution in that way is that, once convened, there would be no restrictions on what can be changed or added if a voting bloc with enough votes was formed to push a particular agenda.  Taking an extreme and unlikely hypothetical situation, one could come out of such a Convention with slavery legal and women not being allowed to vote.

34 states (2/3) are necessary to convene such a convention.  Currently 28 states have passed measures (number changes as some states add, other rescind) calling for/approving of a Constitutional Convention (aka "Article V Convention", after the portion of the Constitution that covers that).

[US Constitution: Article V](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/constitution/article-v.html)

NOTE: I will come back and edit after further researching whether changes made in a Article V Convention would need further ratification by the states, as amendments that are passed by the House and Senate need to be.